# QGIS Import multiple text files at once

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, import, batch, vector-layer

I have been needing to import anywhere between a few to 10's of text layers into a project per day for my job.

- The text files are in a .log format (Space Delimited)
- The X, Y, and CRS designations are the same for all of the files

Is there a plug-in or python command that would help me import these files more efficiently?

Comment: Do you mean that each is being appended to a single dataset, or are they being preserved as separate layers?

Comment: They are being preserved as separate layers